# PostgreSQL - Quartz JDBC-JobStoreTX - getTriggersForJob - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

DB: PostgreSQL 9.2

Hosting: Openshift

Configuration:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = OneTimeJob
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true

org.quartz.threadPool.class: org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread: true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold: 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = Name

org.quartz.dataSource.Name.connectionProvider.class = com.name.scheduler.DBConnectionProvider
```

Stacktrace:

> An SQLException was provoked by the following failure:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106) at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:65) at
>   com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:62) at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.handleThrowable(NewPooledConnection.java:369)
>   at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getBytes(NewProxyResultSet.java:2795)
>   at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate.getJobDataFromBlob(PostgreSQLDelegate.java:88)
>   at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.getMapFromProperties(StdJDBCDelegate.java:881)
>   at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1778)
>   at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTriggersForJob(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1704)
>   at
>   org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getTriggersForJob(JobStoreSupport.java:2141)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2    at
>   org.postgresql.util.PGbytea.toBytes(PGbytea.java:76)  at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBytes(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2271)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getBytes(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2451)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.getBytes(NewProxyResultSet.java:2781)

***PS: Works with postgres 9.4***

Comment: the SQLException wraps an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Can you show the stacktrace of that wrapped exception (`e.getCause().printStackTrace()`)

Comment: @wero added the stack trace in question.

Comment: @RajdeepSiddhapura : The title is misleading what does this have to do with Quartz ?

Comment: Does "*Works with postgres 9.4*" mean it works with the 9.4 _driver_ and a 9.4 _database_? If yes, did you try the 9.4 driver on the 9.2 database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried "_postgres 9.4 driver_", but still it doesn't work. I am also using [logback](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.3) which has "_postgres 8.4_" dependency. Can this be an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This JIRA https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-15133 has the same stack trace and it tels it is a matter of an out dated driver.

If you have tried with last version of PostgreSQL jdbc driver, maybe you include a dependency from `org.postgresql` groupId, and `logback` depends on old version of driver with `postgres` as groupId, thus you are including both dependencies in your app.

Please, try to exclude the old jdbc version this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And tell us if this exlcusion makes your app to work.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You are welcome, and I am happy to help and hunting a bounty ;)