# Quartz, setting up postgres schema, what should JOB_DATA be?

Tags: java, postgresql, quartz-scheduler

I'm using liquibase to setup the database tables for quartz as per [Bert R recipe](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Bert-R/quartz-repro/master/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml).

What is the correct type for the JOB_DATA columns for postgres?

The raw error is

```
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: 2
at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1538)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
at org.postgresql.util.PGbytea.toBytes(PGbytea.java:76)
```

The base error is in PostgreSQlDelegate.java trying to read the JOB_DATA column from the qrtz_triggers table. This column does have just \x in it.

I have changed the above liquibase file to change the type from BLOB to BYTEA as I was getting an error

```
column "job_data" is of type oid but expression is of type bytea
```

The quartz properties file includes the following settings for the Job Store

```
# Job Store
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = 
org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data type for the column should be **bytea**. Simple way to confirm

1. Go to http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/
2. download your version of quartz and extract it
3. go to docs/dbTables and look for tables_postgres.sql

There you will find the data type of job_data as **bytea**

Now to the second issue you are facing after modifying the data type to **bytea** check out this link to see whether it solves the problem?
[PostgreSQL - Quartz JDBC-JobStoreTX - getTriggersForJob - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32936429/postgresql-quartz-jdbc-jobstoretx-gettriggersforjob-arrayindexoutofboundse)

Answer (score 1):

For those like me who struggled to find the quartz db creation schema, you can also find in the [github repo](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/tree/d42fb7770f287afbf91f6629d90e7698761ad7d8/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore) under *main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/*.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).